# What art style is this?

Tags: style-identification

I am working on an image AI to translate images into different styles of art. What style is this?

[image]

Comment: Hi Shrey, did you create these yourself? If so, what input did you use?

Comment: AI is still a grey area for the site, but in general, digital art is off-topic under the current scope definition. Identifying art styles fits into the site scope as support for handmade art, so I would think that only handmade art would be on-topic for style identification. How you use the answer to a style identification question doesn't affect whether the question is on-topic. These images look digital, but they could have been created by hand. So technically, this question is probably on-topic, but it pushes the boundaries of the intended scope. I'll leave it up to the community to decide.

Comment: The style of the collage aspect is strongly reminiscent of Andy Warhol's work.  However, while Warhol's style is usually labeled as "Pop Art," that designation depends on the subject matter—and unless the subject of these portraits is a celebrity I don't recognize, I don't think it counts as Pop Art.

Comment: @Buzz I think you can post that as an answer. While it hasn't got the ideology behind it, it is still in Pop Art style.

Comment: Yeah nah. Don't think this amounts to any kind of a style beyond descriptions like garish, formulaic, or worse. Not pop because that does require a connection to pop culture... maybe the AI aspect does that, but this is more like amateur digital art. I suppose that could be a style, in its absence of any other style.

Answer (score 4):

Not everything is art, and not everything is style. Also, different people have different opinions about what "art" and "style" are.

I see in your picture 2 things:

- some "crazy" filters applied to some image; no art, no style, just digital processing;
- a [**collage**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collage) of the above-mentioned processed pictures.

I cannot judge if a collage of images of ambiguous value has value in itself just because collage is "a technique of art creation" (as stated on the quoted Wikipedia page).

Answer (score 0):

The style of the collage aspect is strongly reminiscent of [Andy Warhol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Warhol)'s work—in particular, his collages, such as *[Marilyn Diptych](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marilyn_Diptych)* and his other brightly colored portrait collages, with similar but varying images of the same person stacked side by side in multiple rectangular boxes.  So it would make sense to describe this work as "in the style of Andy Warhol."

[image: Marilyn Diptych]

Warhol died in the 1980s and did not live to see the modern revolution in computer graphics and digital art, but it seems certain that he would have welcomed these developments.

Warhol is very strongly associate with the style labeled "[Pop Art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_art)" (and was, most probably, the style's best known practitioner).  However, unless the subject of this portrait collage is a celebrity that I do not recognize, one of the arguably most important elements of Pop Art—the connection with popular, commercial, or "lowbrow" culture—seems to be lacking.  For example probably the most famous of all Warhol's collages of is not of a person at all, but rather of *[Cambell's Soup Cans](https://www.moma.org/collection/works/79809)*.  So I personally would not describe this work as "Pop Art" in the sense that the term was used to describe the works of Warhol (or other artists, such as Roy Lichtenstein or Richard Hamilton).

Comment: Pop Art sometimes used just a few representative colors, but those colors were the best approximations of color from a limited pallet. The pictures in the question use "wrong" and grossly distorted colors, so the faces look clownish and weird. I don't think that was seen in Pop Art.

Comment: I agree that the collages are certainly not a good example. I still believe it can be considered Pop Art (in as far as it is anything), as the colours and lines are exaggerated, and the face is heavily stylized. Pop Art took inspiration from ads and comics (basically trying to make art that visually 'pops', in addition to it being based on popular imagery).
Note that the way the image is presented by the OP, has nothing to do with the style, as it is the way the AI presents them (they are all iterations of the same input).

Comment: It does resemble some artists associated with pop art, such as Julian Opie. But pop art covers a very wide range of styles including photorealism, use of commercial art techniques (e.g. Warhol's use of photosilkscreening), and using high art styles to paint popular subjects. Pop art is less a painterly style than an approach that includes choice of subject.